# Safari does not apply border-radious with Gmaps

Tags: google-maps, safari, css, rounded-corners

I've got a problem with Safari and its famous bug related to border-radious and rounded corners. I'm going to put a Gmap inside a circle and, of course, my code works with all browser except Safari. I just can't resolve.

This is my code

CSS:

```
#map-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  z-index: 9999; 
}

#map-container.round-center {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  border-radius: 175px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 175px;
  -ms-border-radius: 175px; 
}

#map-container #map {
  position: absolute;
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  border-radius: 175px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 175px;
  -ms-border-radius: 175px; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map-container" class="round-center">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function loadmap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        zoom: 8,
        disableDefaultUI: true 
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),
        mapOptions);
}

loadmap();
```

I know that this question has been already asked, but I've not been able to resolve with those solutions. I've opened a new question because I've thought that it could be a problem related to Google Maps and I've not seen any topic about that.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

[This is a screenshot of the result in Chrome](https://googledrive.com/host/0B1Mc_9w5k14Ma2tlaDYyU1c1VjQ/Screen%20Shot%202014-09-09%20at%2011.42.27.png)

Comment: Check this can work http://jsfiddle.net/alxscms/3Kv99/